# Convert automatically into a centralized bean for multiple domain objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, spring

I am creating a project which will respond to collect multiple bean object, save it to the database and return the status of the transaction. There can be multiple objects that can be sent from the client. For each object, they are having separate database thus separate controller.

So I planned to create a framework that can accept multiple objects from multiple controllers and send only one centralized object. Below is my code:

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/stat/player")
public class PlayerController {

    @Autowired
    private StatService<PlayerValue> statPlayer;

    @RequestMapping("/number/{number}")
    public Object findByNumber(@PathVariable String number) { // Here returning Object seem odd
        return statPlayer.findByNumber(number);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public class PlayerServiceImpl implements StatService<PlayerValue> {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerRepository repository;

    @Override
    public PlayerValue findByNumber(String number) {
        Optional<PlayerEntity> numberValue = repository.findByNumber(number);
        return numberValue.map(PlayerEntity::toValue).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

In service I returned the `PlayerValue` object but I want to wrap this object into a centralized bean ResponseValue. I created an aspect for that

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class Converter {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Converter.class);

    @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController *)")
    public void restControllerClassMethod() {}

    private <T> ResponseValue<T> convert(List<T> results) {
        String message = results.isEmpty() ? "No result found" : ResponseValueStatus.OK.toString();

        return new ResponseValue<>(ResponseValueStatus.OK, message, results);
    }

    @Around("restControllerClassMethod()")
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> ResponseValue<T> convert(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        ResponseValue value;
        try {
            Object findObject = joinPoint.proceed();
            List<Object> objects = toList(findObject);
            value = convert(objects);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            throw new StatException(String.format("Exception thrown from %s from %s method with parameter %s", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(), joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), joinPoint.getArgs()[0].toString()));
            //this exception will go in a controller advice and create a response value with this message
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            LOG.error("Exception occurred while converting the object", e);
            throw new StatException(String.format("Exception thrown from %s from %s method with parameter %s with exception message %s", joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName(), joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), joinPoint.getArgs()[0].toString(), e.getMessage()));
        }
        return value;
    }

    private List<Object> toList(Object findObject) {
        List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        if (findObject instanceof List) {
            ((List) findObject).forEach(item -> objects.add(findObject));
        } else {
            objects.add(findObject);
        }
        return objects;
    }
}
```

To sum up, There could be multiple entities similar to PlayerValue. I need a way to return the result in a centralized bean. Above process work, BUT for this, I have to give return type as `Object` in `Controller`. Does anybody have a design idea how can I use return type as List or T in the controller? Also, I know it can be done by implementing a `ValueConverter` interface, but this conversion is straightforward. So it would be nice if any other developer doesn't have to implement the `ValueConverter` everytime he wants to add a different controller.

Also feel free to review the implementation and let me know if anyone has some alternative idea or some comments.

**Note:** I reduce a lot of code in the question so that it can be easier to understand without understanding the actual requirement context. Please do let me know if anyone needs more info.

Comment: You will have a hard time finding out where a NPE happened with the code above. You should always chain exceptions or log them, when you have to throw a new exception (plus some ID so you can figure out which log entry belongs to which new exception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're trying to turn Java into REST - i.e. you'd like to strip the types of your results so you can return anything.

If you do that, `Object` is the common base class unless you introduce a [marker  interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern).

A marker interface would allow you to find out when your code suddenly tries to return something else (for example, when an attacker has found a way to access internal objects via REST).

That said, you should be master of your API. When doing REST, other people will talk to your app. If you're unable to tell which objects are returned, then debugging will become quite hard.

Also, people will not like using your API when you change result objects all the time, breaking their code.

Therefore, I suggest that you at least create classes of objects which all implement the same interfaces to make sure you always return a set of known attributes. That will allow you to supply those objects from different sources while being able to tell in advance when something is going to break.

Comment: Great. Marker interface is needed. Thanks for your help